# is material v2.0.0-alpha.8-2 support angular version 6?

Tags: upgrade, angular-material2, angular6, angular2-upgrade

I am using angular 4.0.0 version and material v2.0.0-alpha.8-2. I want to upgrade angular 4.0.0 to angular 6.0.6.

Is there any way can i used materiel old version (v2.0.0-alpha.8-2) and only update angular(6.0.6) version current project?

Answer (score 1):

No. Angular 6 introduced breaking changes because of the update to the RxJS package. Anything that uses RxJS on Angular 2/4/5 is likely to have errors on Angular 6. This includes Angular Material.